# Microsoft Excel calculation inquiry

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a distribution spreadsheet that has a "total previous distributions" column showing the (obviously) previous distribution for each partner.

This amount is manually update by adding last years distribution number to the existing calculations... for example, +1000+1000+1000+1000+1000+1000 would be the previous six years of distributions of 1000 each and the cell would show 6000.

My question is, can I enter a formula that would take the current distribution (entered in another cell) and add it to the back end of the previous distributions so that the previous distributions would be automatically updated upon the next current distribution entry?

Edit: Can't wrap my brain around the posting of the table so I'll try to explain in more detail.

Column C shows current distribution amount (we'll say 10% of $10,000).  Column D shows previous distribution amount of past 5 years and is made by manually entering the previous five years' distributions every time and looks like +1000+1000+1000+1000+1000.  Next year I'll go in and add +1000 to the end of that string so that it reads $6,000.

Problem is that everyone's distribution amount is different from each other and also varies from year to year.  The most time-consuming part of the distribution is manually entering the previous year's amount at the end of that string for all 50 partners.  I was hoping for a function that would take the current year's distribution amount and add it to the end of the previous distribution string when I enter a new current amount.

Comment: Some diagrams of your data would help us understand your question. Please [edit] your question to include some example (mock) data (before and after). See [Format Text as a Table](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question.

Comment: In psuedo-code something like: `CurrentDist+SUM(PrevDistRange)` might work but I would need to see some example data to be sure.

Comment: I would love to just post the spreadsheet or email it to someone.

Comment: Thanks by the way David and Burgi, I'm going to try the example when I get back home.  You guys are the greatest.

Comment: You appear to have created 2 accounts. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.

Answer (score 1):

Brock - Below is a screen capture of something that could solve part of your problem. Instead of typing all of the previous numbers into a cell, I made a small table. The results of this table can be posted into another cell, anywhere in your workbook.

[image]

Column A just contains the year.

Column B is the distribution for that year. It could contain a formula, if you have other data that defines what the distribution will be. e.g. Cell `B2` might be `=0.1*10000`, as per your example.

Column C is the cumulative distribution. Cell `C2` contains the formula `=B2`, because it is first. Cell `C3` contains the formula `=B3+C2`. Cells `C4` through `C8` are similar ... `C4` contains `=B4+C3`, and so on.

Column E could be a cell anywhere in the report you are making, Cell `E3` contains the formula `=C8`.

To maintain this, year over year, you just need to add a row at the end of the table, and adjust the formula in Cell `E2`.